# Memory consumption on Initializing final static variable with another final static

Tags: java, memory-management, compiler-optimization

My question is, if I creates a final static variable in a class and initialize it with another final static variable (already declared and initialized).
What would be the memory consumption for both the variables.

For example:-

```
class SomeClass{

private static final byte VARIABLE_1 = 0x01;

private static final byte VARIABLE_2 = VARIABLE_1;

...

}
```

What would be the memory consumed by VARIABLE_1, VARIABLE_2 ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Two bytes at most, but they might be completely elided by the compiler or JVM.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, and at runtime, 0 bytes. `final static` **primitives** are in-lined by the compiler they are constants.

Comment: I assume this is to cut on memory consumption and improve efficiency, as it doesn't have to make an extra call to get the value of the variable?

Comment: you are right. This is about improving memory consumption of the code. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @JClassic -  More along the lines of  *this value will never change during runtime, so why not hard-code it and improve efficiency*?

Comment: @HSJ - improve performance of both *memory* (less) and *time* (more)

Answer (score 0):

class files contain a copy of the constant value of any static final fields it uses.so memory it is using is negligible.

Class `SomeClass` declares two constants, `VARIABLE_1` and `VARIABLE_2` , and initializes them with expressions that are compile-time constants.

The compiler knows that `VARIABLE_1` represents the value `0x01` and `VARIABLE_2` 
represents the value `0x01`. When the `SomeClass` class is loaded by a Java Virtual Machine, `VARIABLE_1` and `VARIABLE_2` are not stored as class variables in the method area.

The `VARIABLE_1` and `VARIABLE_2` fields are not class variables, they are constants, the Java compiler places the constant int values they represent into the constant pool of any class that uses them.